# Did mikaail, Jibril and israfil pray funeral prayer of last prophet?

Tags: salat, prophets, malaikah, funeral

Tariq jamil of Pakistan said Mikail, Jibril and Israfil prayed funeral prayer of last prophet. Video available on YouTube.

In another deleted? Video he said even Allah descended to Aisha's room and prayed funeral prayer

Searching Google isn't giving proofs for Jibril or Mikhail praying funeral prayer.

Is what being said about funeral prayer correct as per tabligh jamaat? I'm not asking whether its correct as per authentic hadith.

Comment: This is narrated in a hadith recorded by Tabarani in [Mu'jam al-Kabir](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/3196) near the end of the long hadith, and is weak or rather fabricated, see [مجمع الزوائد ومنبع الفوائد](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33855/2673) and [موضوعات لابن الجوزي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/882/301).

Comment: That's the difference between an Aalim and aabid? An aabid doesnt care about fabricated narrations?

Comment: @Sinner - Please provide the link of the video where Tariq Jameel said that.

Comment: @Ren https://youtu.be/ncYFM1WpBU4. Another one at 8:28 Molana Tariq Jameel Latest | Janaza of Prophet Muhammad Saw | Islamic Stories | Prophet Stories
https://youtu.be/Mw-n1kEETwI

Comment: @Sinner - In that video, Tariq Jameel is saying that Allah himself offered the prayer of Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam). This is blatant Kufr and Shirk.